# Unit test the .doOnError in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a piece of code to send a request via WebClient:

```
public String getResponse(String requestBody){
 ...
    final WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> request =
        client.post().body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody));

    final String resp =
        req.retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class)
            .doOnError(
                WebClientResponseException.class,
                err -> {
                  // do something
                  throw new InvalidRequestException(err.getResponseBodyAsString());
                })
            .block();
 ...
}
```

From the code, it looks like the `InvalidRequestException` will be thrown when the `WebClientResponseException` happens. However, the test throws the `WebClientResponseException` instead of the `InvalidRequestException`.

Here's the part of unit test I wrote to cover the `.doOnError` part. I tried the following:

```
...
when(webClientMock.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
when(requestBodyUriMock.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
when(responseMock.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenThrow(new WebClientResponseException(400, "Bad Request", null, null, null));

try {
      String result = someServiceSpy.getResponse(requestBody);
} catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
      assertEquals(expectedCode, e.getRawStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: you need to raise exception on `retrieve()` method instead of `bodyToMono `

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I tried the way you said, but try-catch still can't capture the `InvalidRequestException`. The function code is not written by me and I'm new to Java. I think my code will throw `InvalidRequestException` when `WebClientResponseException` happens, right? Or it means an `InvalidRequestException` will be thrown only when there's an `error`? If so, how do we let `retrieve()` return an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is I need to wrap the exception in `Mono.error,` and then the `doOnError` will be triggered.

```
when(responseMock.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(Mono.error(thrownException));
```